# Copy Multiple Folders with Similar Directory Structure and Maintain Structure in New Location

Tags: command-line, directory

Looking to do something that is probably pretty simple below is the directory structure:

```
/home/user/app-data/Unique container ID/path/to/files
```

I've tried:

```
cp -r /home/user/app-data/*/path/to/files /storage/location
```

Obviously, this grabs all the files I want, which are at the very end of the target location.  I want to copy that final folder in each of the unique directory structures to a save location and maintain the directory structure from the unique ID onward.  So my end storage product for each of the folders grabbed would look like:

```
/storage/location/Unique ID grabbed by the wildcard/path/to/files
```

Comment: ... so you don't want the files, just the directory structure?

Answer (score 2):

`cp` copies the leaf of the source (last part of the path), and in your case, `*` matches one or more leaf objects. Even if `-r` will copy directories recursively, it's probably better to use `-a` instead to preserve all attributes.

```
cp -r /home/user/app-data/* /storage/location
```

If you need more advanced filter options, you could take advantage of `find` and `cpio` in combination.

In this example we just copy the directory structure:

```
find /home/user/app-data \
  -type d -links 2 -printf %P\\0 | \
   cpio -0 -pvdmu -D /home/user/app-data -- /storage/location
```

(The fact, a directory with no subdirectories only has two hard links `.`, `..` we can make use of `-links 2` to get all end directories, either way how you construct your filter, most important is `find` and `cpio` has the same starting-point).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in */path/to/files
  do
    d="${f%/*}"
    d="/path/to/files/storage/location/$d/"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    echo cp -r "$f" "$d"
  done
```

- **First**, Change `/path/to/files` to reflect the actual source path you want within the `Unique container ID` directories and leave the `*` before it.
- **Next**, change `/path/to/files/storage/location` with the actual destination path where you want to copy your files and leave the `/` after it.
- **Then**, `cd` to `/home/user/app-data`.
- **After that**, run the above code for a dry-run.
- **Finally**, remove `echo` when satisfied with the results to do the actual copying.